# tabularx counts expl3 more than once but LaTeX2 doesn't?

Tags: tabularx, counters, expl3, latex3

I know that `tabularx` runs more than once and leads to calculations being incorrect since some calculations are done more than once.

I have LaTeX2 code with counters that works great in the tabularx environment but the same code (but more flexible with the possibility of more than one numbered list) as expl3 leads to wrong values in the variables.

Is that because counters behave differently? Or is there another reason?
Is there an easy workaround with expl3?

```
\documentclass{article}

% this code works 

%\newcounter{numberedlistcounter}
%\newcommand{\resetnumberedlist}{%
%   \setcounter{numberedlistcounter}{0}}
%\newcommand{\numberedlistitem}{%
%   \stepcounter{numberedlistcounter}%
%   \thenumberedlistcounter}
%\newcommand{\numberitemsinlist}{%
%   \thenumberedlistcounter}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\resetnumberedlist}{O{default}}
{
    \int_gzero_new:c { g__numberedlist_counter_#1_int }
}
\resetnumberedlist

\NewDocumentCommand{\numberedlistitem}{O{default}}
{
    \int_gincr:c { g__numberedlist_counter_#1_int }
    \int_use:c { g__numberedlist_counter_#1_int }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numberitemsinlist}{O{default}}
{
    \int_use:c { g__numberedlist_counter_#1_int }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

    \resetnumberedlist

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l}
    \numberedlistitem \\
    \numberedlistitem \\
\end{tabularx}

    number of items in list: \numberitemsinlist
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't have optional parameters with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`....

Comment: latex counters are stored in a list, and this allows tabularx to restore them correctly. But tabularx knows nothing about expl3 integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabularx` resets all latex counters (using the method used by `\include`) count registers allocated with `\newcount`  or `expl3` do not take part in this mechanism.